# Group data and display on VF Page (use of rowspan)

Tags: apex, visualforce, repeat

I have 5 columns , out of which if data of 4 columns are repeating , the 5th column needs to be grouped.

Name     Designation    Email   Phone   Module

So if we have multiple modules assigned to a single person , one single row needs to be displayed.

Trial so far :

Storing data from 3rd party into map in 4 column key + value format

```
mapAccountTeam.put(Con.Name+Con.Designation+Con.Email+Con.Phone, contactList);
```

**Wrapper Class**

```
public Class GroupWrapper {
    public List<Type> contactWrapperList {get; set;}
    public String groupedVal {get; set;}
    public Integer count {get {return contactWrapperList.size(); } set;}
    }
```

Not sure how to model the two apex repeat based on the key/value.

Can somebody help?

**Controller:**

```
for(CustomerContact__c CustCon : contactList){
        if(mapModule.containsKey(CustCon.Name+CustCon.Designation+CustCon.Email+CustCon.Phone)) {
                List<ContactWrapper> conWrapperList = mapModule.get(CustCon.Name+CustCon.Designation+CustCon.Email+CustCon.Phone);
                ContactWrapper conWrapObj = new ContactWrapper();
                conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Name;
                conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Designation;
                conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Module;
                conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Email;
                conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Phone;
                conWrapperList.add(conWrapObj);
                mapModule.put(CustCon.Name+CustCon.Designation+CustCon.Email+CustCon.Phone, conWrapperList);
        }

        else
         {
        List<ContactWrapper> conWrapperList = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        ContactWrapper conWrapObj = new ContactWrapper();
        conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Name;
                conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Designation;
                conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Module;
                conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Email;
                conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Phone;
                conWrapperList.add(conWrapObj);
                mapModule.put(CustCon.Name+CustCon.Designation+CustCon.Email+CustCon.Phone, conWrapperList);      
    }

      }
       moduleList = new List<String>(mapModule.keySet()); 
       system.debug('moduleList'+moduleList);
```

**VF:**

```
<apex:repeat id="myRepeatHeader" value="{!moduleList}" var="key">
    <tr>    

        <td rowspan="{!mapModule[key].size()}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!mapModule[key].Name}"/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!mapModule[key].Designation}"/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!mapModule[key].Email}"/>
        <apex:outputText value="{!mapModule[key].Phone}"/>   
        </td>
        <apex:repeat id="contactDetails" value="{!mapModule[key]}" var="con">
        <tr>
            <td><apex:outputText value="{!con.Module}"/></td>

        </tr>
       </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Table :

Name    Designation Email   Phone   Module

Roger   Manager abcd@abcd.com   555 Module 5 Module 6

Rita    Senior Manager  xyz@abcd.com    222 Module 1 Module 2

Comment: how do you like to see, can you post a picture with a kind of excel format

Comment: Can you please close this question if it solves your purpose

Answer (score 6):

I will take this approach to prepare the structure like this:

> 1) Create a ContactWrapper with all the Contact attributes.
>
> 2) In `getData()` method, retrieve the Contact List firing SOQL query and prepare the desired map i.e. mapModule which contains ModuleName as Key and `List<ContactWrapper>`. In that method, prepare a List of ModuleNames from `mapModule.keySet()`.

```
public class ContactController{
    //map to capture Module Name and List of Contacts
    public Map<String, List<ContactWrapper>> mapModule {get;set;} 

    //map to capture Module Name and count of Contact which will be used to define rowspan.
    public Map<String, Integer> moduleCountMap{get;set;}

    //to capture list of Module Names
    public List<String> moduleList {get;set;}

    public ContactController()
    {
        mapModule = new Map<String, List<ContactWrapper>>();
        moduleCountMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        moduleList = new List<String>();
    }

    //prepare data to display in Visualforce.
    public void getData()
    {
        List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT Name, Phone, Email, Module__c 
                                            FROM Contact 
                                            WHERE Module__c !=null 
                                            ORDER BY Module__C LIMIT 10];

        //grouped into module and prepare the map
        for(Contact conObj:contactList)
        {
            List<ContactWrapper> conWrapperList = new List<ContactWrapper>();
            //verify map already contains same Module Name
            if(mapModule.containsKey(conObj.Module__c))
            {
                //retrieve the list of existing contact
                conWrapperList = mapModule.get(conObj.Module__c);

                //put the new contact to the list
                conWrapperList.add(new ContactWrapper(conObj));

                mapModule.put(conObj.Module__c, conWrapperList);
                modulecountMap.put(conObj.Module__c, conWrapperList.size());
            }
            else
            {
                //create a new map of Module Name
                conWrapperList.add(new ContactWrapper(conObj));
                mapModule.put(conObj.Module__c, conWrapperList);
                modulecountMap.put(conObj.Module__c, conWrapperList.size());
            }
        }

        //create a list of Module Names which will be helpful to iterate
        moduleList = new List<String>(mapModule.keySet());  
    }

    public Class ContactWrapper {

        public ContactWrapper(Contact conObj)
        {
            this.Name = conObj.Name;
            this.Phone = conObj.Phone;
            this.Email = conObj.Email;
            this.Module = conObj.Module__c;
        }

        public String Name {get;set;}
        public String Designation {get;set;}
        public String Phone {get;set;}
        public String Email {get;set;}
        public String Module {get;set;}
    }
}
```

**Visualforce**

> 1) First, repeat through `moduleList` which contains all the Module Name as key.
>
> 2) To determine, `td rowspan` get the size by `{!modulecountMap[key]}`.
>
> 3) Create an inner repeat which have List of ContactWrapper which we can easily retrieve by `{!mapModule[key]}`

```
<apex:page controller="ContactController" action="{!getData}">
  <table border="1">
   <tr>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    </tr>    
     <apex:repeat id="myRepeatHeader" value="{!moduleList}" var="key">         
         <apex:variable var="count" value="{!1}"/>            
            <apex:repeat id="contactDetails" value="{!mapModule[key]}" var="att">
                <tr>
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!count==1}">
                        <td rowspan="{!(modulecountMap[key])}"><apex:outputText value="{!att.Module}"/></td>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!att.Name}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!att.Phone}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:outputText value="{!att.Email}"/></td>

                    <apex:variable var="count" value="{!count+1}"/>
                 </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>    
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

I have tried to visualize like this:

[image: Table data]

At my dev org, it is showing like this. I am not showing designation column

[image: rowspan]

To get a help on how to use rowspan, refer [td row span](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_td_rowspan.asp)

Comment: Santanu thanks for the descriptive answer . My requirement is actually to group the rest of the fields together if they are repeating and make Module be of multiple rows. I have modified your code to suit my requirement . However getting some errors in the VF Page . Seems like accessing the elements is not being done in a right way . Please find in the edit and let me know if you see any obvious error.

Comment: what type of errors you are facing?

Comment: do not change my answer, rather change your question and put your codebase

Comment: Apologies , I put it here by mistake . I am getting } missing error . But I suspect it's something else. Please take a look at the code . I am not sure if mapModule[key].Phone this way of accessing elements is the issue

Comment: td rowspan will give you the issue, you have to create a separate map to store the count and use that in rowspan.

Comment: You have just copy-pasted wrongly, conWrapObj.name = CustCon.Module;